# C Compare enumerate with invalid value

Tags: c, enums, comparison

I would like try to understand how is working the compilator when we compare an enumerate with invalid value, and what the program is doing during execution.

I found strange source code during my work, and did not understand the behaviour of the program, which was not giving me the expected result.

I wrote the following little program to summarize my problem.

I create an enum E_Number and I instanciate a variable `a`, with the value `-1`. 
Then I perform comparison on `a` to check if it belongs to the range of the enum.

(I know, this is really strange, but this is exactly what i found in source code !)

I expected the result tells me *Not in range* because of the fail of the first condition `(a >= FIRST_ENUM)`. 
But it was the fail of the second condition `(a < NB_MAX_NUMBER)` which gave me the right result (see the `printf()`)...

If I cast `a` in `(int)` in the `if` conditions, I get excepted results.

So what is happening during the execution ? Is the program considering `-1` as an other possible enum value which will be positionned after `NB_MAX_NUMBER` ? What is the rule for `>` and `<` operator on enum ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST_ENUM 0
typedef enum{
    NUM_1 = FIRST_ENUM, 
    NUM_2, 
    NUM_3,
    NB_MAX_NUMBER
}E_Number; 

int main()
{
    E_Number a = -1; 

    if ((a >= FIRST_ENUM) && (a < NB_MAX_NUMBER))
    {
        printf("In Range\n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not in Range\n"); 
    }

    printf("1st condition = %s\n", (a >= FIRST_ENUM)?"TRUE":"FALSE"); 
    printf("2nd condition = %s\n", (a < NB_MAX_NUMBER)?"TRUE":"FALSE"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

> gcc program.c
>
> .\a.exe
>   Not in Range
>   1st condition = TRUE
>   2nd condition = FALSE

I am working with MINGW compilator ( gcc (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2 )

Comment: Funnily enough, I can't reproduce the result (MSVC), the last two being FALSE and TRUE respectively, as I would expect.

Comment: I don't like the way it is written. If one wants an "invalid" `enum` member, it should be made a part of the `enum`.

Comment: Are you sure that program shown here is the program you compiled and executed ?

Comment: How would "cast `a` in `(int)` in the `if` conditions" help? That part was working as you expected. There is no `if` in the part that apparently gave the wrong results.

Comment: Thanks to the answers; I didn't know that `enum` can be `unsigned`.

Comment: @eugene-sh I undertand your comment ! This code exists in aeronautic sofware, and when a function "receive" the enum value, it is not sure the result is valid and belongs to the range of the enum...

Comment: @weather-vane The 2 answered post give your answer !

Comment: @mahesh Yes it is the same !

Comment: One conclusion I got for this problem when I had it some months ago, was to never ever use the `enum type` again, and instead always use `int` when I store or `return` an enum.  That way I know exactly (well, not exactly because `int` is not fixed width, but as exact as it can be) the type of the variable.  At least I can guarantee I fill not find any `unsigned` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from `ISO/IEC 9899:1999`, 6.7.2.2p3

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined, 108) but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration.

So, when you declare an enumeration, you cannot be sure a priori about what kind of data will the implementation of C choose to store that variable.  Optimisation reasons, the compiler may not choose an integer type on 4 bytes if you store enumeration constants between [-128, +127]. The implementation may choose char to store an enumerated variable, but you cannot be sure.  Any integer data type can be chosen as time as it can store all possible values.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the compiler consider `E_Number` as `unsigned int` because all the legal values are unsigned, so -1 is considered to be ~0u which is >= FIRST_ENUM and < NB_MAX_NUMBER

I have the same behavior with `gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1)`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out 
Not in Range
1st condition = TRUE
2nd condition = FALSE
```

But, if I change your definitions like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST_ENUM -1
typedef enum{
    NUM_1 = FIRST_ENUM, 
    NUM_2, 
    NUM_3,
    NB_MAX_NUMBER
}E_Number; 

int main()
{
    E_Number a = -2; 

    if ((a >= FIRST_ENUM) && (a < NB_MAX_NUMBER))
    {
        printf("In Range\n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not in Range\n"); 
    }

    printf("1st condition = %s\n", (a >= FIRST_ENUM)?"TRUE":"FALSE"); 
    printf("2nd condition = %s\n", (a < NB_MAX_NUMBER)?"TRUE":"FALSE"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

the behavior change and the enum is considered to be an int and I have :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out 
Not in Range
1st condition = FALSE
2nd condition = TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumarator constants are of [type `int`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3). The enumerator type is an unspecified integer type capable of representing all the enumerator constants.

[6.7.2.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p4):

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined,128) but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration. The enumerated type is
>   incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list of
>   enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter.

Since you haven't enumerated any negative values, that type may well be an **unsigned** type. If it is, then `(E_Number)some_integer` will always be greater than or equal to zero (`0==FIRST_ENUM`).

If you expand the `enum` list to:

```
typedef enum{
    NUM_NOPE=-1,
    NUM_1 = FIRST_ENUM, 
    NUM_2, 
    NUM_3,
    NB_MAX_NUMBER
}E_Number;
```

you'll force the compiler to use a signed type and the results will reverse.